# How to perform column level validation by joining one Big data frame to many small data frame in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one big tables or data frame that has more than 50 millions records  and 135 columns .
Now for each row i need to perform validation for more than 50 columns .

So basically for each row each columns i need to get corresponding value from all 25 tables .

I have listed here only 4 small tables but in my case i will have 25 such tables .

For example here is one of my validation called CityId Validation .

To do CityId Validation we need TownCode from Table2 by passing physicalstateorprovincecode ,physicalcountrycode and physicalcityname from Tables1

With TownCode i have to go to Table3 pass physicalcountrycode,physicalstateorprovincecode and TownCode and get CityID.

If CityID is available then it is correct elase false .

Here is how my data frames looks like .

And above logic is example for one of the column but i have to do such validation for more than 50 columns.

Can we do this in spark ?

Table1 Main Table (50 Millions Records)

```
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------------------+
|filler1|dunsnumber|businessname                               |tradestylename              |registeredaddressindicator|physicalstreetaddress    |physicalstreetaddress2|physicalcityname|physicalstateorprovincename|physicalcountryname|physicalcitycode|physicalcountycode|physicalstateorprovincecode|physicalstateorprovinceabbreviation|physicalcountrycode|physicalpostalcode|physicalcontinentcode|mailingaddress|mailingcityname|mailingcountyname|mailingstateorprovincename|mailingcountryname|mailingcitycode|mailingcountycode|mailingstateorprovincecode|mailingstateorprovinceabbreviation|mailingcountrycode|mailingpostalcode|mailingcontinentcode|nationalidentificationnumber|nationalidentificationsystemcode|countrytelephoneaccesscode|telephonenumber|cabletelex|faxnumber |chiefexecutiveofficername|chiefexecutiveofficertitle|lineofbusiness                           |sic1|sic2|sic3|sic4|sic5|sic6|primarylocalactivitycode|activityindicator|yearstarted|annualsaleslocal  |annualsalesindicator|annualsalesinusd|currencycode|employeeshere|employeeshereindicator|employeestotal|employeestotalindicator|includeprinciplesindicator|importexportagentindicator|legalstatus|filler2|statuscode|subsidiarycode|filler3|previousdunsnumber|financialstatementdate|filler4|headquarterorparentdunsnumber|headquarterorparentbusinessname            |headquarterorparentstreetaddress|headquarterorparentcityname|headquarterorparentstateorprovincename|headquarterorparentcountryname|headquarterorparentcitycode|headquarterorparentcountycode|headquarterorparentstateorprovinceabbreviation|headquarterorparentcountrycode|headquarterorparentpostalcode|headquarterorparentcontinentcode|filler5|domesticultimatedunsnumbers|domesticultimatebusinessname          |domesticultimatephysicalstreetaddress|domesticultimatecityname|domesticultimatestateorprovincename|domesticultimatecitycode|domesticultimatecountrycode|domesticultimatestateorprovinceabbreviation|domesticultimatepostalcode|globalultimateindicator|filler6|globalultimatedunsnumber|globalultimatebusinessname            |globalultimatestreetaddress           |globalultimatecityname|globalultimatestateorprovincename|globalultimatecountryname|globalultimatecitycode|globalultimatecountycode|globalultimatestateorprovinceabbreviation|globalultimatecountrycode|globalultimatepostalcode|globalultimatecontinentcode|numberoffamilymembers|diascode |hierarchycode|filler7|filler8|urldomain               |naics1|naics2|naics3|naics4|naics5|naics6|publicprivateindicator|obindicator|latitude  |longitude  |oporactdescpart1                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |oporactdescpart2|oporactdescpart3|oporactdescpart4|oporactdescpart5|nixieindicator|delistindicator|primary8digitsic|primary8digitdescription                                    |primarynaicsdescription                                        |natlidfull|transactionalindicator|
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------------------+
|       |001007108 |DOLGENCORP, LLC                            |DOLLAR GENERAL              |N                         |1342 PINE ST             |                      |UNADILLA        |GEORGIA                    |USA                |008857          |296               |019                        |GA                                 |805                |31091             |6                    |              |               |                 |                          |                  |               |000              |000                       |                                  |000               |                 |                    |                            |                                |0001                      |4786279585     |          |          |EVE MEADOWS              |MANAGER                   |VARIETY STORES                           |5331|    |    |    |    |    |                        |000              |0000       |000000000000000000|                    |000000000000000 |            |0000006      |1                     |              |                       |Y                         |G                         |000        |       |2         |0             |       |000000000         |00000000              |       |068331990                    |DOLGENCORP, LLC                            |100 MISSION RDG                 |GOODLETTSVILLE             |TENNESSEE                             |USA                           |003754                     |203                          |TN                                            |805                           |370722171                    |6                               |       |006946172                  |DOLLAR GENERAL CORPORATION            |100 MISSION RDG                      |GOODLETTSVILLE          |TENNESSEE                          |003754                  |805                        |TN                                         |370722171                 |N                      |       |006946172               |DOLLAR GENERAL CORPORATION            |100 MISSION RDG                       |GOODLETTSVILLE        |TENNESSEE                        |USA                      |003754                |203                     |TN                                       |805                      |370722171               |6                          |11210                |005479269|02           |       |       |                        |452319|      |      |      |      |      |                      |N          |+32.252708|-083.740074|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |                |                |                |                |N             |N              |53310000        |VARIETY STORES                                              |ALL OTHER GENERAL MERCHANDISE STORES                           |          |C                     |
|       |001132690 |ADVANCE AMERICA, CASH ADVANCE CENTERS, INC.|ADVANCE AMERICA             |N                         |332 N L ROGERS WELLS BLVD|                      |GLASGOW         |KENTUCKY                   |USA                |003211          |060               |033                        |KY                                 |805                |421411300         |6                    |              |               |                 |                          |                  |               |000              |000                       |                                  |000               |                 |                    |                            |                                |0001                      |2706511990     |          |          |LISA BROWN               |MANAGER                   |PERSONAL CREDIT INSTITUTIONS             |6141|    |    |    |    |    |                        |000              |0000       |000000000000000000|                    |000000000000000 |            |0000002      |0                     |              |                       |Y                         |G                         |000        |       |2         |0             |       |000000000         |00000000              |       |179469978                    |ADVANCE AMERICA, CASH ADVANCE CENTERS, INC.|135 N CHURCH ST                 |SPARTANBURG                |SOUTH CAROLINA                        |USA                           |008468                     |839                          |SC                                            |805                           |293065138                    |6                               |       |078454395                  |EAGLE U.S. SUB, INC.                  |135 N CHURCH ST                      |SPARTANBURG             |SOUTH CAROLINA                     |008468                  |805                        |SC                                         |293065138                 |N                      |       |811589639               |GRUPO ELEKTRA, S.A.B. DE C.V.         |AV. FERROCARRIL DE RIO FRIO NO. 419 CJ|CIUDAD DE MEXICO      |CIUDAD DE MEXICO                 |MEXICO                   |009100                |000                     |CDMX                                     |489                      |09310                   |5                          |04316                |008037671|03           |       |       |WWW.ADVANCEAMERICA.NET  |522291|      |      |      |      |      |                      |N          |+37.006016|-085.924526|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |                |                |                |                |N             |N              |61410000        |PERSONAL CREDIT INSTITUTIONS                                |CONSUMER LENDING                                               |          |C                     |
|       |001134456 |PEOPLE'S UNITED BANK, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION |                            |N                         |126 DANIEL ST            |                      |PORTSMOUTH      |NEW HAMPSHIRE              |USA                |006885          |725               |057                        |NH                                 |805                |038013857         |6                    |              |               |                 |                          |                  |               |000              |000                       |                                  |000               |                 |                    |                            |                                |0001                      |               |          |          |BARBARA CONDA            |MANAGER                   |NATIONAL COMMERCIAL BANKS, NSK           |6021|    |    |    |    |    |                        |000              |0000       |000000000000000000|                    |000000000000000 |            |0000015      |0                     |              |                       |Y                         |G                         |000        |       |2         |0             |       |000000000         |00000000              |       |072147077                    |PEOPLE'S UNITED BANK, NATIONAL ASSOCIATION |850 MAIN ST FL 6                |BRIDGEPORT                 |CONNECTICUT                           |USA                           |000677                     |112                          |CT                                            |805                           |066044917                    |6                               |       |800407673                  |PEOPLE'S UNITED FINANCIAL, INC.       |850 MAIN ST                          |BRIDGEPORT              |CONNECTICUT                        |000677                  |805                        |CT                                         |066044917                 |N                      |       |800407673               |PEOPLE'S UNITED FINANCIAL, INC.       |850 MAIN ST                           |BRIDGEPORT            |CONNECTICUT                      |USA                      |000677                |112                     |CT                                       |805                      |066044917               |6                          |00583                |014029370|02           |       |       |WWW.BRANCHES.PEOPLES.COM|522110|      |      |      |      |      |                      |N          |+43.077690|-070.755372|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |                |                |                |                |P             |N              |60210000        |NATIONAL COMMERCIAL BANKS                                   |COMMERCIAL BANKING                                             |          |C                     |
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+----------------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+------------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------------+-------+------------------+----------------------+-------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+----------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------------------+
```

reference Tables very very small tables not more than 10MB size

Table2

```
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------+--------------+
|COUNTRY_CODE|COUNTRY_NAME|PROVINCE    |PROVINCE_CODE|TOWN_CODE|TOWN_NAME     |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------+--------------+
|021         |ANDORRA     |null        |000          |000002   |ALDOSA        |
|021         |ANDORRA     |null        |000          |000013   |EL TARTER     |
|033         |ARGENTINA   |BUENOS AIRES|001          |000223   |OLIVOS        |
|033         |ARGENTINA   |BUENOS AIRES|001          |000226   |PABLO PODESTA |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------+--------------+
```

Table3

```
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|CityID|TownCode|CountryCode|StateCode|   
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
|110880|006129  |805        |001      |
|110888|007554  |805        |005      |
|111164|004661  |805        |009      |
|111368|005193  |805        |075      |
+------+--------+-----------+---------+
```

Table4 Identifier

```
+----------------+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+----------+------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|IdentifierTypeId|Value |EntityId  |ValueTypeId|EffectiveFrom       |ProviderId|ProviderType|SourceUpdateDate|SourceLink|SourceType|EffectiveToNACode|EffectiveToMinus|EffectiveTo           |EffectiveFromNACode|EffectiveFromPlus|NaCode|IsPrimary|ValueOrder|ValueTypeCode|EntityType|EntityTypeId|SysFrom             |SysFileId           |
+----------------+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+----------+------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|320114          |3339  |4294963171|320114     |1/1/1997 12:00:00 AM|null      |null        |null            |null      |null      |NA02             |null            |12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM|null               |null             |null  |False    |1         |Naics        |Industry  |404008      |7/2/2015 12:00:00 AM|2015-07-02-0000.Full|
|320114          |333997|4294963154|320114     |1/1/1997 12:00:00 AM|null      |null        |null            |null      |null      |NA02             |null            |12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM|null               |null             |null  |False    |1         |Naics        |Industry  |404008      |7/2/2015 12:00:00 AM|2015-07-02-0000.Full|
|320114          |333999|4294963153|320114     |1/1/1997 12:00:00 AM|null      |null        |null            |null      |null      |NA02             |null            |12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM|null               |null             |null  |False    |1         |Naics        |Industry  |404008      |7/2/2015 12:00:00 AM|2015-07-02-0000.Full|
|320114          |334   |4294963152|320114     |1/1/1997 12:00:00 AM|null      |null        |null            |null      |null      |NA02             |null            |12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM|null               |null             |null  |False    |1         |Naics        |Industry  |404008      |7/2/2015 12:00:00 AM|2015-07-02-0000.Full|
+----------------+------+----------+-----------+--------------------+----------+------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+------+---------+----------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in Spark. And there are two approaches:

1. Do [`broadcast`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html) on small tables and then use `filter` or `where` on big table
2. Do [`broadcast join`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html)

Here is basic example of first approach.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Main {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sql = new SQLContext(sc)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import sql.implicits._

    // Creating a DataFrame with valid data. Column names will be _1 and _2
    val validDataRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (10, 20), (20, 31), (30, 40), (100, 200), (200, 300)))
    val validDataDf = sql.createDataFrame(validDataRdd)

    // This is the big DataFrame. Column name is _1
    val theData = sc.parallelize(1 to 10000).toDF()

    // To broadcast data it first need to be brought locally
    val localValidData = validDataDf.collect()    // One can, instead of broadcasting Array[Row] transform Row into some custom case class for more convenient processing
    val broadcastedValidData = sc.broadcast(localValidData)

    // It's easier to do filtering on RDDs, but it also possible to use DataFrames.
    theData.rdd.filter(rowBig =>
      broadcastedValidData.value.exists(row => row.getAs[Int](0) == rowBig.getAs[Int](0))
    ).collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

**EDIT (added broadcast join example):**

```
val ordersByCustomer = ordersDataFrame
    .join(broadcast(customersDataFrame), ordersDataFrame("customers_id") === customersDataFrame("id"), "left")
  ordersByCustomer.foreach(customerOrder => {
    println("> " + customerOrder.toString())
  })
```

Comment: So you are suggesting to do broadcast on all 25 small tables .And then use filter from big tables? Is it possible to put small example?

Comment: Thank you so much I am going through that

Comment: I got way ahead from your answer but i am trying to put in my question perspective ..Where do i have to perfrom Join in this case ? Sorry for the late comment but i was trying out ..

Comment: If you want to go with join approach - you don't need to broadcast anything and you don't need filter either. You only need to write join the way it is specified in documentation. I'll add broadcast join example to my answer.

Comment: So for each column i have to perform join .As i mentioned in the question i have to perform validation for each row and for each row almost every column .This answer is usefull but i am not able to upvote ..Only accent answer is the option

Comment: If you need to validate multiple columns - I think it's best to use broadcast and filter. This way you will need to go through the big table only once.